# SQL Server - select column by condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if there is an option to select columns by condition.

The SQL query is to get 2 rows from a table, then compare each column value of those two rows.

I want the selected column to be the columns with non-matching values

```
select * (only column with different values)
from Account c 
where c.DistributorID = "ID"
  and c.AccountID = "ID" or c.AccountID = "ID"
```

****** edit ************

this is my first question, so sorry if I wasn't clear about it..

(index)----AccountID----DistributorID ----Name --- City --- Fun

1----------12345-------------2------------dan-------NY-------5

2----------45678-------------2-----------daniel-----NY-------6

I want to create a query that select and display only the columns with a different value, in this example I what to see the result:

(index)----AccountID------- Name----Fun

---1--------12345-----------dan------5

---2--------45678----------daniel----6

Comment: Sample data and desired results will help us understand your question.

Comment: As posted this is not at all clear what you are trying to do. Maybe distinct, maybe a join, maybe something completely different.

Comment: c.AccountID = "ID" or c.AccountID = "ID"  ??

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  If no one understands what you want, no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to type out all your columns. This would mean your select becomes:

`select column1,column2`

If you want to remove rows where column1 and column2 are equal then your query becomes:

```
select Column1, Column2
from Account c 
where c.DistributorID= "ID"and 
c.AccountID = "ID" or c.AccountID = "ID" 
AND Column1 != Column2
```

Comment: when using OR operators its always a good idea to use brackets

Comment: the problem with this solution is that I got 75 column for each table and I have 6 tables.

Comment: You have 6 tables with 75 columns each that you want to compare with eachother? Thats (75*(5*75))+(75*(4*75))+(75*(3*75))+(75*(2*75)) = 78750 comparisons. Or don't I understand your question (or is my high school math off)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your looking for then your solution is probably going to be in dynamic sql.  If you look in sys.columns filtered by the object_id of your table then you will get a list of columns.  If you use that list to return column name if content of column name does not match then you can structure something to return that data.

Assuming you are going to use this for spotting differences between rows, I'd suggest output of three columns: Column name, valueInRow1, valueInRow2 as being a more readable result set.  Please note this is going to be a fairly chunky and complex piece of TSQL however, not a simple query.

The technique here is fairly well documented as individual items, although not put together quite like this.  If your completely stuck and have no idea where to start then let me know and I'll get you going.  Hopefully this will be enough to set you on a path though.

Comment: this is exactly what I want (sorry if I wasn't that clear about it).
Column name, valueInRow1, valueInRow2
But I really don't know where to start from? is there any document I can read about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to get values in your result set depending on a certain condition. If that is the case then [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) (pun intended) may help you solve your problem:

```
select *, CASE c.AccountID 
                      WHEN "ID1" THEN ColumnForID1
                      WHEN "ID2" THEN ColumnForID2
                      END
from Account c 
where c.DistributorID= "ID"and c.AccountID in ("ID1", "ID2")
```

Comment: tnx' but this is not the case, what I want is to get all of the columns with a different value for 2 different row